# BF3 saving favorite servers

Tags: battlefield-3

Wandering amongst several servers during matchmaking, I often come close to some that I would like to find again in my next matches.

During a match, in the server settings section I can see there is an option to add the server to favorites.

Sometimes I did, but I'm not able to find them again in "my servers", or I don't understand the meaning of "my servers" in BF3 multiplayer main menu.

Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'My Servers' page is for all the servers you currently have rented out, not your 'Favourite' servers.

I'm not sure what system your playing on but on PS3 to find your favourite servers go to the server browser then hit **L1** or **R1** to move across to 'Favourites' tab. It will be similar on Xbox anyway - use the top shoulder buttons to move across. Obviously on PC you can just click the tab.

[image: Favourites - PS3]

Comment: Oh, nice. Since I never use server browser, I thought that favorites were shown into "my servers". Don't know why, I think simple ideas association. Thanks, anyways.